# Traversing javascript promises tree

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to javascript promises and tried to solve the subsequent problem:

There is a tree with nodes that have a structure like this

```
node: {id, children:node[]}
```

one node is received by calling

```
getNode(id)
```

where getNode returns a javascript promise

so I get one node object by

```
getNode(id).then(function(node) {
   id = node.id;
   children = node.children;
```

})

Now I want to get the whole tree in one object like

```
treeObject = getTree(rootNodeId)
```

so that in the end contents of treeObjects should be for example

```
 {1,children:
         [{2,children
              [{5,null},{6,null},{7,null]},
           {3,children[{8,null},{9,null]}...
```

???
thanks for any answers!

Comment: Sounds like you need a recursive function?

Comment: What is children ?

Comment: What issue are you having meeting requirement?

Comment: Is `children` an array of nodes, or an array of node ids (so that you need to use `getNode` again)?

Comment: node ids. I think Jonas told a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
async function getTree ( id ){
  const node = await getNode(id);
  node.children = await Promise.all( node.children.map(getTree));
  return node;
}
```

or without async await:

```
 function getTree ( id ){
  return getNode(id).then(function(node){
   return Promise.all( node.children.map(getTree)).then(function(children){
      node.children = children;
      return node;
   });
 });
}
```

assuming that *children* is a list of ids

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. Unfortunately my browser doesn't support async/await but only Promises. Until now I haven't managed to transform this solution into Promise-only version. Maybe someone could help with this? Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: @Wieland Jonas has updated his answer with a version of the code that doesn't require `async`.

Comment: @wieland perfect! ;) youre welcome... If this answered your question, feel free to tick the green checkmark...