# Iterating over Promises recursively

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, promise

I have an REST API interface which only gets me the first level of some information.

So for example I want to collect groups. Every Group can have subgroups. So for example "Group 1" has the Subgroups "Group A" and "Group B". "Group A" has the Subgroup "GroupX". And so on.

But the API only gives me the first level of Groups for a group name. So I pass "Group 1" to the API and it returns "Group A" and "Group B". To get the supgroups of Group A, I need to call the API again. But i don't know how many iterations of this it will have.

So I thought about using recursion but I haven't come far.

So far my Code:

```
getGroupChildren(group:string){ return this restService.getGroupChildren(group)}

getGroups():Promise<any>{
  let collection:string[] = [];
    return this.getGroupChildren("Group A").then((result)=> {
      if(result.data.length !==0){
         return this.getGroupChildren(data[0].groupName);
      }
    });
}
```

Now this will only return me the first Supgroups of the first element.

How can I accomplish it will always find every Supgroup no matter how many? Maybe is it good to use Observables?

Here an example structure of one API call:

```
{  "groupName" : "Group_1",  "children" : ["Group_A", "Group_B"]}
```

Comment: What does your data look like? How would you know if there are more levels to go deep?

Comment: Have you tried to put a debugger inside `then` callback of `getGroupChildren` and see what happens after 1st iteration? what value you get/passed for `data[0].groupName`?

Comment: This might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863275/traversing-javascript-promises-tree

Comment: That's the thing I don't know how many levels there will be. So I need to it dynamically. I will call for every Group the ressource and for its children and if I get an empty array it means there are no subgroups for this group anymore and I stop.

Comment: It's unlikely that observable will offer something different. It's regular recursive function. I'd suggest to go `async` instead of raw promises to make it easier. The actual solution is unclear because the question doesn't contain enough data. What exactly is the function supposed to return? It's called getGroups but returns a single string.

Comment: I added an example of the Response. I returns an object with a Data array of strings.

Comment: Can't you do this on the server? Having the front end work out if it has all the info it needs is not the most efficient practice when it could result in many REST calls

Comment: What is the final structure you want to get? A flat array of all the groups, of only the leaves of the group tree, or some nested object structure?

Comment: Just an array of strings, of all the groups. But I think even if I want another structure, I don't think this will be a problem. I only want to call the Promise so long, until I get no more data.

Comment: OK, I answered with an object structure, since a flat array could bring up the question about order, and then knowing which is the parent-child relationship. The nested object structure has the information need to create a flat array from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `flatMap` operator of `Observable`

```
getGroups(group: string) {

    return this.http.get(`/group/{group}`).flatMap(response => {
        if (response.children.length === 0) { // you hit a leaf, stop recursion here
             return Observable.of(response);
        } else { // there are more levels to go deeper
             return this.getGroups(response.children[0].groupName);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit** Using Promise

Let's say you use a `GroupService` which returns the data instead of `HttpClient`. You can convert a `Promise` to an `Observable` with `fromPromise` operator.

```
getGroups(group: string) {

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.groupService.get(group)).flatMap(response => {
        if (response.children.length === 0) { // you hit a leaf, stop recursion here
             return Observable.of(response);
        } else { // there are more levels to go deeper
             return this.getGroups(response.children[0].groupName);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit 2** Using this service

Let's take a look at your example. You have following json

```
{
    "groupName": "Group_1", 
    "children" : ["Group_A", "Group_B"]
}
```

In your component file, you call the service as follows

```
...
this.recursiveGroupService.getGroups("Group_1")
    .subscribe(response => {
        // at this point response will be `Group_A`
    })
```

**Edit 3** Getting the whole object

This time we'll use `forkJoin` and call `getGroups` for all of the children and collect the results in a `children` array.

**Note:** I haven't tested this code myself. It may contains some error. If it has, let me know.

```
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getGroups(group: string) {
    let retVal;
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.groupService.get(group)).flatMap(response => {
        retVal = {
             groupName: response.groupName
        };
        if (response.children.length === 0) { // you hit a leaf, stop recursion here
             return of(retVal);
        } else { // there are more levels to go deeper
             // this will create list of observable for each child
             const children$ = response.children.map(
                       child => this.getGroups(child)); 
             // forkJoin will execute these observables in parallel
             return forkJoin(children$).pipe(
                  map(results => {
                      // results is an array containing children data
                      retVal.children = results;

                      return retVal;
                  })
             );
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. But since I haven't done much with Observables, how do I convert that? I use a Framework which only returns Promises, so I only have a service class, which provides me a method of type Promise for the API call

Comment: You can always use `Observable.fromPromise` which will convert a `Promise` to an `Observable`. The rest is in my answer

Comment: Ok and then I subscribe to it in my code, where I call getGroups()? Sorry, but I am very new to Observables.

Comment: Thanks the recursive Part works perfect. However I still face problems now with my output structure. In your example I will get only the children of the last node. But since I want the full tree in the end I am kind of looking for an easy way, to iterate over them.

Comment: @user5417542 I have updated my answer, please test it.

Comment: I receive an error at the forkjoin().pipe() line, it says it can't find the map function

Comment: Did you `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` ?

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius :). Works perfect. Now I have to figure out how it works exactly. Is there a good ressource for this?

Comment: I'm glad it works :) Can you mark it as accepted? There are tons of documentation on RxJs. You should look at how to use RxJs operators like `flatMap` `forkJoin` and others. This decision tree may help too -> http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#tree

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Promise.all` to recursively resolve deeper children, and then take the result (an array) to create an object to resolve the promise with:

```
getGroups(groupName = "Group A") {
    return this.getGroupChildren(groupName).then((result) =>
        Promise.all(result.data.map( ({groupName}) => this.getGroups(groupName) ))
    ).then(children => ({ groupName, children }));
}
```

So the promised value could be something like:

```
[{
    groupName: "Group A",
    children: [{
        groupName: "Group A1",
        children: []
    },  {
        groupName: "Group A2",
        children: []
    }]
}]
```