# Angular 5 Observable and recursivity

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to develop a function to call recursively an url using RxJs observable in Angular 5.

The api sends me results by page so I have to send a http request until I've got no more result. Inside my results, I've got a "next" url. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529232/angular-2-http-observables-and-recursive-requests?rq=1) to achieve this but it doesn't work, my script doesn't stop...

Here what I've done :

```
    // service.ts

  getAllProductsByBundle(bundleId) {

        let url = this.getUrl(bundleId);
        url += "/products";

    //url = http://api.test.com/bundle/{bundleId}/products

        let httpParams = new HttpParams();
        httpParams = this.getUrlParameters('GET');

    //url becomes = http://api.test.com/bundle/{bundleId}/products?page=1

      // headers
        var headers = this.setHttpHeaders();

        const getNextByUrl = (nextUrl?: string): Observable<any> => {
            if (nextUrl) {
                url = nextUrl;
            }

            return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: httpParams});
        }

        return getNextByUrl().expand((response) => {
            if (response['products']['_links']['next']) {

                return getNextByUrl(response['products']['_links']['next']['href']);
            }
            else {
                return Observable.empty();
            }
        }).map(result => result );
    }
```

Here a sample of result (json) I've got :

```html
{
 "products": {
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 20,
  "pages": 2,
  "total": 27,
  "_links": {
   "self": {
    "href": "http://api.test.com/bundle/5ad5ea2ce13d707f303be6d2/products?page=1&limit=20"
   },
   "first": {
    "href": "http://api.test.com/bundle/5ad5ea2ce13d707f303be6d2/products?page=1&limit=20"
   },
   "last": {
    "href": "http://api.test.com/bundle/5ad5ea2ce13d707f303be6d2/products?page=2&limit=20"
   },
   "next": {
    "href": "http://api.test.com/bundle/5ad5ea2ce13d707f303be6d2/products?page=2&limit=20"
   }
  },
  "_embedded": {
   "items": [{
    // items from 1 to 20
   }]
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you very much :)

EDIT :

```
    getAllProductsByBundleId(bundleId) {
        let url = this.getUrl(bundleId);
        url += "/products";

        return this.findProductsRecursively(url);
    }

    findProductsRecursively(url) {

        let httpParams = new HttpParams();
        httpParams = this.getUrlParameters('GET');

        // headers
        var headers = this.setHttpHeaders();

        console.log(url);

        return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: httpParams}).flatMap(response => {

      // here the url is good but it's still the same (page=2)
      // the response['products']['_links']['next'] is still the same url
      // it's like the second url is not launch
            console.log("next");
            console.log(response['products']['_links']['next']);

            if (response['products']['_links']['next']) { 
                // there are more levels to go deeper

                console.log("go deeper");
                if (response['products']['_links']['next']['href'])
                    return this.findProductsRecursively(response['products']['_links']['next']['href']);
                else 
                    return Observable.of(response);

            } else { 
                // you hit a leaf, stop recursion here
                return Observable.of(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

the console.log

```
next
bundle.service.ts:100 {href: "http://api.test.com/bundle/id/products?page=2&limit=20"}
bundle.service.ts:105 go deeper
bundle.service.ts:95 http://api.test.com/bundle/id/products?page=2&limit=20
bundle.service.ts:99 next
bundle.service.ts:100 {href: "http://api.test.com/bundle.../products?page=2&limit=20"}
bundle.service.ts:105 go deeper
bundle.service.ts:95 http://api.test.com/bundle/id/products?page=2&limit=20
bundle.service.ts:99 next
```

EDIT 2 : this.getUrlParameters('GET'); was the problem because this function add a "page=1" after my url. So I've got page=2&...&page=1 in my url.

The solution : [Iterating over Promises recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357961/iterating-over-promises-recursively/49358049#49358049)

Comment: This might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357961/iterating-over-promises-recursively/49358049#49358049

Comment: let's try it :) thank you

Comment: Same problem, my script doesn't stop... I'm going to edit my first post

Comment: If your code is ok, then your data may be problematic. What I mean is that your json could always have `next` url available. Check your data and make sure it's not causing an infinite calls.

Comment: It looks like, you always get `{href: "http://api.test.com/bundle/id/products?page=2&limit=20"}` as `next` url. There may be something wrong with your backend or your request parameters

Comment: Yes that was I though but, the second page returns no "next" url (previous, first and last only). 

I finally found my problem. this.getUrlParameters('GET'); add a "page=1" after each request... half day lost for that. Developer job is amazing :D Thank you for your help