# function wrapping promise get undefined typeof then

Tags: javascript, promise

I passed an `fn` as a parameter to apply to each node in my tree-traversing function. I'm trying to check whether `fn` is a promise by using `typeof fn.then === 'function'` (if it is, I will need to use a "promising" version of traversing as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863275/traversing-javascript-promises-tree)). As the definition of `fn`, if I wrap a new promise into a function for accepting the `node` parameter, the above check returns `undefined` instead of `function`.

```
<script>
let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let y = 2;
  resolve(y);
});

let promise2 = function(y){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(y);
  });
};

alert ('typeof promise1.then: ' + typeof promise1.then + '\ntypeof promise2.then: '  + typeof promise2.then);
</script>
```

Comment: _"Demo code is here"_ should be a [mcve] and not a link to an external resource

Comment: @Andreas -- usually I use plunker for the demo code and I saw other people do the same here. The demo code itself is complete and verifiable if you may simply take a look. I have no idea why I get a '-1' in 5 seconds after I posted; I feel you are very Irresponsible.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time**._"

Comment: Surely you would need to check if the return value of the function is a promise, not check if the function is a promise.

Comment: @Jaybird -- appreciate it if you may indicate how can I check the return of a function from its definition.

Comment: I think you'd have to call the function and see what the return value is. Hopefully there is no possibility of a function that sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns something else.

Comment: Avoid having a function that might return a promise or a function which in turn returns a promise. For the sake of readability you should always return one type. For example, you might wrap the Promise, you'd otherwise directly return, into a function. Can you provide a more elaborate (but as short as possible) example how you call such a function? Apart from that better probe for a promise using `foo instanceof Promise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to check whether something is a promise; if it is, I will need to use a "promising" version of traversing

Don't do that. Returning different types (result vs promise-for-result) from the same function is very confusing, and dynamically switching between a "normal" and a "promising" version inside your function won't make your code easier to maintain either.

Just provide two different functions, a synchronous one that expects plain values from its callback and an asynchronous one that expects its callback to return promises. There, you'd simply cast any return value to a promise using `Promise.resolve(…)` instead of testing whether it is a promise (or something similar) or not.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(…)` seems to be a practical solution to wrap `fn` "whether it is a promise (or something similar) or not" and makes a then-able.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the purpose of `Promise.resolve` :-)